Not able to add any package in PyCharm 2023.3.5 on windows
I'm trying to download packages in PyCharm like pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter.

System: windows64

Python Version: 3.11.0

PyCharm: Community Edition 2023.3.5


This is the error message:
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/openpyxl/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/openpyxl/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skippingCould not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/openpyxl/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/openpyxl/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/openpyxl/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/openpyxl/WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/openpyxl/ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl==3.2.0b1 (from versions: none)ERROR: No matching distribution found for openpyxl==3.2.0b1


Perhaps you have a firewall in place? Is this your personal computer or work provided?

Oh it could be! This is my work laptop.
I had no issue opening pypi.org though.

I've seen a case when PyCharm wouldn't install a package. But, using, for example: "pip install pandas" in a virtual environment activated terminal window, would work.
